# How to extend sample size from true population

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, genetic-algorithm

Let’s say I have sample of 200 people (rows) with their personal information (eduction, gender, occupation etc). Is it possible to create artificial 2000 samples based on my original sample of 200 through any algorithm ?if so what and how? 
Genetic Algorithm come in mind..

Comment: This is a much more appropriate question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but there are many ways to do so. Oversampling is the most straightforward, but if you're looking to create new observations that are different than your existing you could look at SMOTE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because higher-level statistics questions belong on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure the purpose of your question, could use "resampling" if you are trying to:

1.Estimating the precision of sample statistics (medians, variances, percentiles) by using subsets of available data (jackknifing) or drawing randomly with replacement from a set of data points (bootstrapping)

2.Exchanging labels on data points when performing significance tests (permutation tests, also called exact tests, randomization tests, or re-randomization tests)

3.Validating models by using random subsets (bootstrapping, cross validation)
Common resampling techniques include bootstrapping, jackknifing and permutation tests.